# приведение типа в конструкторе

Tags: c++

Есть класс:

```
template <typename T> 
 class A
 {
    public:
      explicit A(vector<T> _v):v(_v) {}
    private:
      vector<T> v;
 };
```

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы работало:

```
int main()
{
   vector<__int32> v;
   A<__int64> a(v);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    explicit A(vector<T> _v): v(_v){}
    template<typename U, typename = enable_if_t<is_convertible<U, T>::value>>
    explicit A(vector<U> _v):v(_v.begin(), _v.end()) {}
private:
    vector<T> v;
};
```

Суть в чём: для того же самого типа мы оставляем простое копирование, а вот для других типов мы используем инициализацию через итераторы(т.к. у вектора конструктор копирования только для того же самого типа есть), при этом мы оставляем вторую версию только для тех типов `U`, которые могут быть сконвертированы в исходный тип `T`

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что только примерно так - добавив:

```
template<typename U>
    explicit A(vector<U> _v) {
        v.resize(_v.size());
    copy(_v.begin(),_v.end(),v.begin());
}
```

Тогда для того же типа вызовется более точный :) конструктор, а для вашего случая - этот.